# ASP.net MVC RTM - "project type is not supported"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

After installing ASP.net MVC, when I attempt to load a existing or a new MVC application (straight from New Project - A project for creating an application using the ASP.NET MVC framework (1.0) (.NET Framework 3.5)) I get the following error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The project file 'path' cannot be opened.

### The project type is not supported by this installation.

### OK   Help

Tried reinstalling which didn't help. Tried devenv /setup which also didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason was because I didn't have the Visual Web Development part of VS installed. I only had the C# language. As such, MVC didn't check and installed successfully but couldn't use the underlying part.

After installing the Web Dev bit everything worked as expected...

Comment: `Control Panel` > `Programs` > `Programs and Features` > `Visual Studio 2010 Professional` > `Uninstall/Change` > `Add Feature`...

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to run the following command:

```
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
```

This will try to load any Visual Studio packages that failed previously at some point, such as the WPF project flavor package, which would cause the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same issue but going through the uninstall and re-install of beta and RC versions and finally the RTW I ended up with two ASP.NET MVC Web Application icons in my "File/New/Project" dialog.

If I click the first link, my project does not load correctly.  But if I click the second one everythign works great.

I haven't dug into the templates folder to see if there is a remnant from a previous version or what.

Brian

Comment: Hi Brain, thanks for that.  I only have the one template, this laptop only ever had RTW installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install SP1 for .Net and VS2008?

Answer (score 0):

The way I corrected this issue of not being able to open a ASP.NET MVC 1.0 for myself goes like this when I was using VS 2008

- Install SP1 for VS 2008
- Install MVC 2.0 framework
- I realized I had an MVC 1.0 project and I used this [tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) to change the project to MVC 2.0.

The tool works great, props to Eilon Lipton never met the guy but I'm down with anyone that will make my life easier.

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx